# I have two pages one page is select2 jquery plugin When I access this page in another page select2 is not loading

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-select2

Please see the below information:

I have three pages:

- Projects
- Tasks
- Timesheet

I want all these page accessible using ajax. I did also everything is working fine.

But I have used `select2 jquery plugin` in Projects page and Tasks Page.

When I am trying to access using ajax the select2 dropdown is not loaded properly.

It showing an error:

```
$().select2 is not function.
```

I added all js files and css files in header.

When I open `mysite/myprojects/projects.php`, it is working well but When I access this page using ajax from`mysite/projects/front`, its not working.

Please advise me what Can I do?

Comment: Are you double including `select2` function in your page? And how are you accessing view of page via ajax?

Comment: When you say you want these pages accessible using ajax do you mean loading the page content dynamically into another web page? If so you will have problems binding jquery events to content loaded using Ajax.

Comment: yes I resolved it using added jquery in header. thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes I resolved it using added jquery.js in header.